# close() func of http.client.HTTPConnection doesn't work?

Tags: python, http, python-3.x, websocket

Python version I used is 3.3. 
It is supposed that I can't send a http request, with a closed connection. but actually, it still works after close() function called. Here is my code:

```
conn = http.client.HTTPConnection("192.168.8.186:8081")  
conn.request("GET", "")  
response = conn.getresponse()  
data = response.read()  
data  
b"403 Forbidden \nRequest forbidden by administrative rules.\n\n'"
conn.close()   #??? 
conn.request("GET", "")  
(conn.getresponse()).read()  
b'403 Forbidden\nRequest forbidden by administrative rules.\n\n'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the code of `HTTPConnection` it seems that the `request` call in turn calls `send` which opens the connection if not open:

```
def send(self, data):
    """Send `data' to the server."""
    if self.sock is None:
        if self.auto_open:
            self.connect()
        else:
            raise NotConnected()
    ...
```

From this piece of code it seems that setting the `auto_open` flag to 0 (it's 1 by default) can avoid this behavior. In that case you'll probably need to call the `connect` function yourself.

This is based on my code for Python 2.7.3 however.

Comment: It's the [same in 3.3](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c3896275c0f6/Lib/http/client.py#l836).